# DibiFluent and SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS

Tags: php, sql

I need your help with SQL statement prepared using DibiFluent.

```
// For example, DISTINCT works
$fluent = dibi::select('DISTINCT *')
    ->from('users')
    ....

// ... but this does not (which should, imho)
$fluent = dibi::select('SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *')
    ->from('users')
    ....
```

Could someone contribute to this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty easy I guess :) You have some query like:

```
$sql = dibi::select('username')     
                -> from('users')
                -> where('id = %i', $user_id);
```

Now, you have to set flag:

```
$sql ->  setFlag("SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS");
```

Then, you can fetch all data:

```
$result = $sql -> fetchAll();
```

And finally, here is the miracle:

```
$myTotal = dibi::select(" FOUND_ROWS()")->fetchSingle();
```

Enjoy ;)